# Help with setting up my VPN servers

Tags: 16.04, vpn

I have followed multiple different forums and haven't been able to get it right. I would really appreciate the help. I can connect to it but it doesn't show the VPN server IP it continues to show the house IP. The server also times out alot and stops working. Any help?

Comment: This is a VPN server at work and/or place of education?  Connecting to one isn't a matter of just entering the server address.  There are a lot of settings behind it.  Is there a system administrator you can ask for the VPN settings for a Linux-based machine?  And you might want to consider upgrading your version of Ubuntu...that might make a difference.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  *You've tagged an EOL/ESM release*

Comment: If you set up the vpn server and you are using openvpn then there is an option in the config file of the server to force the clients to send all traffic over the vpn, this isn't the default.  If the vpn server is on your own network then it will show your external IP address.  Look for push "redirect-gateway def1"